# Conditional Formatting Excel Coloring

Tags: excel, format

I have a spreadsheet where I want to highlight column H6 yellow but only if column J6 = KP. What is the easiest way to do this? I have tried adding a rule in with conditional formatting, but can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: Conditional formatting.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do but can't seem to get it to work :/

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question with what exactly you're trying?

Comment: What's the *specific rule* you're trying?

Comment: Do you mean Cell J6 equals Cell KP?

Comment: No cell J6=KP (KP are initials). If it is initialed then I want to highlight cell H6 yellow. Does that make sense?

Comment: `=J6="KP"` should be the formula you're trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question, use a conditional formatting rule based on the formula:

```
=J6="KP"
```

and apply the rule to cell `H6`.